# Security Filter Chain is still working even though already setting permitAll() In Spring Boot version 3.0.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am currently developing Spring boot web service with Spring boot version 3.0.6. When I am working with Spring security for User will sign up and login by using Authentication Controller. When User login the Server will return JWT with contains userName and person Role.

Here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Resource
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(){
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder())
                .and().build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/create-employee").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.getRole())
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/*").permitAll() // this should not go through filter
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl())
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    return http.build();
}
```

}

Here is My Custom Once Per Request Filter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Resource
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@Resource
private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(jwt)){
        throw new InvalidInformationException("Your request doesn't have jwt"); 
    }
    jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwt);
    String userName = jwtTokenUtil.getUserNameFromToken(jwt);
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

    if(userDetails != null && userDetails instanceof CustomUserDetails ){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if(bearerToken == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
        return bearerToken.substring(7);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

And here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

@Resource
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Resource
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@Resource
private UserFacades userFacades;

@PostMapping(value = "/create-user")
@ResponseBody
public GlobalMessage createNewCustomer(@RequestBody CreateNewCustomerRequest request){
    UserValidation.validateRegisterInfo(request.getUserName(), request.getPassword());
    UserValidation.validatePersonalInformation(request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName(), request.getPhoneNumber(), request.getEmail(), request.getHomeNumber());
    return userFacades.createNewCustomer(request);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/login")
public JWTRespond signIn(@RequestBody SignInRequest request){
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUserName(), request.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken((CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal());
    return new JWTRespond(jwt);
}
```

When I use Postman to send The sign up request to server through: `http://localhost:8081/api/v1/auth/create-user`

**This error appears:**

```
com.example.flowershop.exceptions.InvalidInformationException: Your request doesn't have jwt
    at com.example.flowershop.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
```

Sorry, I am new guy in Spring Boot. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

I expected the only request that didn't have `permitAll()` will go through my Custom Filter.

Comment: Yes it should go through the filter `permitAll` isn't the same as no security and skip all filters!. There is also an issue with your setup you need an `FilterRegistationBean` as currently your filter is registered and executed twice (once as part of the regular filter chain and one as part of Spring Security, you need to disable the first). You also need to improve your filter to just skip the fact that there is no jwt token and just proceed. Spring Security will handle the rest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude authentication to pass by filter In spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050456/exclude-authentication-to-pass-by-filter-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common misunderstanding. `permitAll` doesn't mean bypass all filters (or some filters, or ...) it means anyone can access it. This still means your filter will be executed, because if one is authenticated you might want to know.

The problem is your filter, which is assuming too much (especially because you also have basic authentication enabled). Remove the throwing of an error and always continue the process. Spring Security should handle the unauthenticated user etc.

```java
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Resource
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@Resource
private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(jwt)){      
      jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwt);
      String userName = jwtTokenUtil.getUserNameFromToken(jwt);
      UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

      if(userDetails != null && userDetails instanceof CustomUserDetails ){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if(bearerToken == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
        return bearerToken.substring(7);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now your filter will just continue and Spring Security will handle, as it should, the error if someone has no token (or is allowed to access certain URLs).

There is another issue with your configuration, when Spring Boot detects a `Filter` it will automatically register it. Currently your filter is executed twice. What you need to do is add a [`FilterRegistrationBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html) to disable the default registration for this filter.

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> jwtAuthenticationFilterRegistrationBean(JwtAuthenticationFilter filter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
  frb.setEnabled(false);
  return frb;
}
```

Now your filter is only part of Spring Security and not the regular filter chain anymore.

Answer (score 0):

By default, All API end points will be passed through filters. From the question you asked I understand that you want your custom filter class with name

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
```

with method

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
```

to exclude the below api end point from filtering

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/auth/create-user
```

**For this we need to tell spring secuirty to exclude few filters from filtering for few specific end points. This can be done by overriding a method from **OncePerRequestFilter** class.**

```
private static final String[] excludedEndpoints = new String[] {"api/v1/auth/create-user"};
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    logger.info("Omitting request from filtering");
    return Arrays.stream(excludedEndpoints)
            .anyMatch(e -> new AntPathMatcher().match(e, request.getServletPath()));
}
```

The above code exclude the execution of filter for the api call to **"api/v1/auth/create-user"**

Make sure that "api/v1/auth/create-user" api endpoint should be permitted without authentication using **permitAll()** in the bean which returns **SecurityFilterChain**.