# Unable to access actuator health endpoint

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am unable to access the actuator health endpoint on my service.

This is the web security configuration code:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain enableSecurity(
      HttpSecurity http,
      AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter,
      AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider,
      JwtAuthenticationFailureHandler jwtAuthenticationFailureHandler)
      throws Exception {
    log.info("Enabling Security");
    log.info("authenticationFilter : {}", authenticationFilter);

    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .cors()
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(
            "/resources/**",
            "/static/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/javascript/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/actuator/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling(
            exceptionHandling ->
                exceptionHandling.accessDeniedHandler(jwtAuthenticationFailureHandler));

    return http.build();
  }
```

In the properties file, I have set the following:

management.security.enabled = false
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health

However, when I call GET http://localhost:8086/my-service/actuator/health, it returns 403.
It is still calling the authenticationFilter class and returns "Token not found in request".

This is the class implementing AuthenticationFilter for reference:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Profile({"local", "dev", "sit", "uat", "prod"})
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AuthenticationFilter {

  private final JwtService jwtService;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
      @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
      @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String jwt = this.getJWT(request);
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(jwt)) {
      this.validateToken(jwt, request, response);
    } else {
      throw new TokenRequiredException("Token not found in request");
    }
    log.info("SecurityContextHolder.getContext() : {}", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234296/security-filter-chain-is-still-working-even-though-already-setting-permitall-i

Comment: Or implement the handling of jwts using the actaully recommended way that is declared in the spring security documentation.